# Knife Project not available 2.8 (trying to cut two shapes out of one)

Tags: mesh, knife-tool, svg

For some reason my knife project is not available when I search it, the only thing that comes up is knife, I am trying to cut one shape out of another shape but keep both shapes in tact so I would essentially have two new shapes. Is there another way I could do this?

Comment: you need to select the first object, then the second, then go in Edit mode, then header menu > Mesh > Knife Project

Comment: Oh thank you so much, I was going crazy trying to find it.

Answer (score 3):

You need to select the first object, then the second, then go in *Edit* mode, then header menu > *Mesh* > *Knife Project*. Note that it will take your view angle into account.

[image]

If you want to project the inner edges of a mesh (like the rays of the circle on the image below) you need to delete its faces.

[image]